# React Router props: what is the correct type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I create a router custom component to do a redirect in case some parameters are not present:

```
const StateParamRoute = (props: any) => {
  ...
  return stateParam ? <Route {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/error" />;
};
```

Then, I use it as:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <StateParamRoute path="/" exact component={TestScreen} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

But I am getting a warning in the console saying:

```
Line 48:23:  Unexpected any. Specify a different type  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
```

I know I can ignore this, or disable the checking on eslint config, but I would like to solve it.

I have tried:

```
type CustomRouterProps = {
  path: string,
  exact: boolean,
  component: React.ReactNode
}

const StateParamRoute = (props: CustomRouterProps) => {
...
}
```

But it does not work...

Comment: What error do you get when you use the second type?

Comment: @TusharShahi the error said component was not compatible, I have change it to component: ComponentType<any>, and it solves the error, but triggers warning on the "any" :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use the types from `@types/react-router-dom` and import it like so:

```
import { RouteProps } from 'react-router-dom';

const StateParamRoute = (props: RouteProps) => {
...
}
```

Comment: I was sure I tried that too, it worked!!! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So far I found if I do:

```
type CustomRouterProps = {
  path: string;
  exact: boolean;
  component: ComponentType<ReactNode>;
};

const StateParamRoute = (props: CustomRouterProps) => {
...
}
```

The warning is gone, but I am not sure if it is the best solution.